# "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to String" php

Tags: php

for some reason $Value throws this error (Yes, I am sure about this, if I remove it from the query, the error is not thrown -- obviously this makes the code useless though, also if I try to assign $value to another variable before it also throws the error).

### This is the var_dump() of $PLChecked if needed.

array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["Plugin ID"]=> string(1) "2" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["Plugin ID"]=> string(1) "3" } }

---

```
$PLChecked = [];
foreach ($a as $b){

$checkNum = $;

$result = mysql_query("Select `cc` FROM `aa` WHERE `Checksum` LIKE '$checkNum'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `ID` FROM `aa` WHERE `cc` LIKE '$checkNum' LIMIT 1");
    $value = mysql_fetch_object($result); //here i would like to get the selected ID
    $PLChecked[] = $value;
}
}


 foreach ($PLChecked as $Value)
{   

    //$a;
    $sqlano = "SELECT `Link` FROM `aa` WHERE `ID`LIKE '$Value'"; // This throws the error -- or at least that's what php says.
    //$resultawqe = mysql_query($sqlano);
    //$value = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sqlano));

    //$PLLinks[] = $resultawqe;
}
```

Now, I have this exact code in another part of the code and it runs fine (actually the query is slightly different but it's fundamentally the same).
I don't know why it does this.

**By the way if it's something easy to fix please post a hint as the answer, later, when selected as correct, you can add the actual fix.**

**Thanks**

Comment: So what is the value of `$Value`; the error tells you that it's a StdClass object, not a string

Comment: PS, learn about parameterised statements for SQL queries

Comment: And what you'e looking for is `$Value->{'Plugin ID'}`

Comment: @MarkBaker I edited the code, now you may be able to help me, for example in the first foreach loop, it seems that I am saving something that I wanted to save as strings as an StdClass Object. How would i save that to an actual String?

Comment: As you're using `mysql_fetch_object`, that's what you get, an object.... you'll always get an array or an object from a database fetch, and it's up to your code to extract a string from that

Comment: Also, just for your reference, the mysql extension has been removed from the more recent versions of PHP; you should be using the mysqli or pdo extensions instead

Comment: Why should I switch to mysqli? The solution that I am using works even in mysql and I am using mysql way to unescape strings so theoretically I should be safe from injection.

Comment: No, it doesn't guarantee you safe from injection, escaping only protects against certain exploits, but there are other exploits being used aginst which escaping won't protect you, but where bind variables with prepared statements will keep you safe

Comment: As to why you should switch.... because if you ever upgrade your PHP, then __the mysql extension has been removed from the more recent versions of PHP__ as I stated previously.... that's a pretty good reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values which you add to the PLChecked array using foreach loop should be of type "string".
Adding to PLChecked should be like $PLChecked[] = $value->ID instead of $PLChecked[] = $value; Because $value is an object and it contains the ID you selected from the query.

Comment: Well how can mysql_fetch_object() fetch a string instead of an object? Is there a more specific way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `ID` FROM `aa` WHERE `cc` LIKE '$checkNum' LIMIT 1");
    $value = mysql_fetch_object($result); //here i would like to get the selected ID

     // if $value is object or array then you will loop through it like
    foreach($value as $val){
      $PLChecked[] = $val->ID; in case of object 
      $PLChecked[] = $val['ID']; in case of array
    }

}

 foreach ($PLChecked as $Value)
 {   

     // now variable $value will contain ID and the below query will work. 
     $sqlano = "SELECT `Link` FROM `aa` WHERE `ID`LIKE '$Value'"; 

 }
```